# Update with inner join using spark dataframe/dataset/RDD

Tags: sql, sql-server, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am transformaing ms sql server query's logic to spark. Thge query to be transformed is as under:

```
Update enc set PrUid=m.OriginalPrUid
FROM CachePatDemo enc 
inner join #MergePreMap m on enc.PrUid=m.NewPrUid
WHERE StatusId is null
```

I am using data frame for the transformation and I have two tables in my two dataframes which I am joining as an inner join. I need to find a way to take all the columns of table 1 and updated columns(which are commonin both tables).

I tried using this:

```
val result = CachePatDemo.as("df123").
  join(MergePreMap.as("df321"), CachePatDemo("prUid") === MergePreMap("prUid"),"inner").where("StatusId is null")
  select($"df123.pId", 
         $"df321.provFname".as("firstName"), 
         $"df123.lastName", 
         $"df123.prUid")
```

It doesn't seem to solve my issue. Can anyone please help?

Comment: schema of the two input dataframe and schema of the output dataframe should help you get answers quickly

Comment: What the `newdf` and `df2` refer to in your code? Clarify (not in comments please, edit your post)

Comment: Would you care please reviewing your question please ? I believe there is some inconsistancy in the code that you have provided. Yet also I don't see where you have added the null condition in your spark-sql query.

Comment: @AlexSavitsky  updated the question

Answer (score 0):

On Spark 2.1 This works

```
case class TestModel(x1: Int, x2: String, x3: Int)

object JoinDataFrames extends App {
  import org.apache.spark.sql.{DataFrame, SparkSession}
  val spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("GroupOperations").master("local[2]").enableHiveSupport.getOrCreate

  import spark.implicits._
  import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

  val list1 = (3 to 10).toList.map(i => new TestModel(i, "This is df1 " + i, i * 3))
  val list2 = (0 to 5).toList.map(i => new TestModel(i, "This is df2 " + i, i * 13))
  val df1: DataFrame = spark.sqlContext.createDataFrame[TestModel](list1)
  val df2: DataFrame = spark.sqlContext.createDataFrame[TestModel](list2)
  val res = df1.join(df2, Seq("x1"), "inner")
  println("from DF1")
  res.select(df1("x2")).show()
  println("from DF2")
  res.select(df2("x2")).show()
}
```